# Как изменить размер цифр у графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

Использую font для изменения шрифта у подписей на осях графиков:

```py
font =  {'family': 'serif',
         'color': 'darkred',
         'weight': 'normal',
         'size': 16,
         }
x = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 100)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*x) * np.exp(-x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'k')
plt.title('Dampled exponential decay', fontdict=font)
```

А что в него добавить, чтоб шрифт цифр тоже можно менять?

[image]

Comment: за код скриншотом - сразу минус и голос за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: @strawdog это даже не скриншот, а фото экрана 

Comment: Я извиняюсь,  просто нет кода под рукой, а очень нужно разобраться в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, вы не используете ООП-подход для работы с графиками, поэтогу вам должно подойти

```
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
```

Если бы использовали ООП-подход (через axes), то нужно было бы сделать так:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=16)
```

Comment: а что оператор `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` переводит код в ООП?

Comment: @splash58 не код переводит, а стиль работы - напрямую с объектами.

Comment: а почему plt не объект? вы не подумайте, что я дурака валяю, я правда не понимаю вашей фразы, и мне как слабому спецу в ООП интересно

Comment: @splash58 а это не моя фраза: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html